# Print line after matching a regex pattern

Tags: regex, sed, awk, gawk

I am new to awk and am stuck on this problem. Basically I am searching for a pattern and I want to separate each match with a "--" so I can easily use a yaml library in ruby to parse out file

```
awk '/(start)/,/(end)/' #awk command I am doing
```

**What I get:**

```
start
foo
bar
end
start
foo2
bar2
end
start
foo3
bar3
end
```

**What I want:**

```
start
foo
bar
end
--
start
foo2
bar2
end
--
start
foo3
bar3
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is to check when the range ends and print those dashes. So I changed the implicit default `print` by an explicit one with that condition:

```
awk '/start/,/end/ { print ( $0 ~ /end/ ) ? $0 "\n--" : $0 }' infile
```

It yields:

```
start
foo
bar
end
--
start
foo2
bar2
end
--
start
foo3
bar3
end
--
```

Comment: We all love Birei! Not sure what less than 3 means. But yeaaah!! +1

Comment: Don't do that as it requires specifying the end condition twice.

Answer (score 4):

code for sed

```
sed '/end/a --' file
```

```
start
foo
bar
end
--
start
foo2
bar2
end
--
start
foo3
bar3
end
--
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using an address range:

```
awk 'NR>1 && $1=="start" {print "--"} 1'
```

Answer (score 2):

#### awk (without address range, only ONE condition):

```
awk '1;$0=="end" {print "--"}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using /start/,/end/ is never a good idea as it introduces duplicate code if you want to just do trivial things like print a line before/after the block or exclude the lines containing the start/end pattern. Just keep it simple and explicit:

```
$ awk '/start/{f=1} f; f&&/end/{print "--";f=0}' file
start
foo
bar
end
--
start
foo2
bar2
end
--
start
foo3
bar3
end
--
```

Comment: But as I heard an address can be executed faster than testing each line. Can I get "nicer" code and pay with speed?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

`awk '1;/^end$/{print "--"}' file`

The `1` prints each line unconditionally. ("If expression `1` is true, do the default action, which is `print`".)
The second pattern then prints `--`, but only if the line matches `^end$`